TailwindCss has different colors in Dist Build and run Dev
I need to help please, I have been building a project with tailwindCss and React, with Vite, but when I build my project then generate the dist carpet, but the colors are different when I run project in dev, I'm going to show you an image.
I only put it on within my index.css, but when I generate my build and run preview, my localhost page has a color different than localhost dev run
This is the localhost build:

This is my localhost dev (I want it):

I only have it within my index.css and tailind.config, the rest are components with tailwind css classes


Does anyone know some solution to it? or What I'm missing?
I want to deploy it in Vercel, but the build is deployed with different colors than localhost dev run,
I need a solution to resolved it.
Thanks.

I noticed the scrollbar style is different in both images. Are you using the same browser?

I also noticed that, but you can see that the colors in sidebar also is different in both images, one looks darker and the other brighter. Yes, I'm using chrome.

I don't think it's necessarily an issue with Tailwind or your project. Try checking if the problem also exists in other browsers?

Maybe some selectors with equal Specificity is overwritten by another differently due to their appearance order changed in the generated style sheet between dev and production? I've faced this problem with media query modifiers when using tailwind with NextJS. You can start with debugging the scrollbar style as it is the most obvious difference.
